# Learning resources for blind LaTeX beginner

Tags: learning, accessibility, tutorials

On the Blind Math list I've been asked for "a guide to get started with LaTeX". I welcome suggestions. I've take a look at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner), but unfortunately it seems not to address accessibility for blind users.

I don't think there's a single good answer to this question. Much depends on the needs and wishes of the person using the guide. In this case the person is "interested in math in particular, not publishing books whatever".

To help users choose a guide, if possible I'd appreciate a brief description of any suggested guide, both in terms of content and purpose, and in terms of accessibility. But don't let that be an obstacle to making a suggestion.

You can find the Blind Math post asking for help at
URL: http://nfbnet.org/pipermail/blindmath_nfbnet.org/2023-September/010801.html

Comment: https://learnlatex.org should be accessible (if issues arise they can be raised as feature requests) or some posts here https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Baccessibility%5D+blind (not that many, actually) most posts under the accessibility tag are about generating accessible documents for blind readers, not helping blind authors.

Comment: Please help me standing in your shoes: do you ask for short summaries to better select which ones to spend time on reading? And if so, what makes it difficult or distracting to read? Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO What do you mean 'what makes it difficult or distracting to read?'? I'm not sure what that's a reference to?

Comment: @cfr, I just assumed that reading text via fingertips or via speech, in contrast to via eyes, may feel a bit like reading source code, e.g. from HTML, rather then rendered text. Is it true? I.e. where non-blind people can glance over pages, is it something which is hard to do via finger tips or speech conversion?

Comment: @MS-SPO Possibly, but, unless I've misunderstood, the OP wants to read the summaries in order to decide what to recommend to the enquirer. Perhaps I'm mistaken, but I understood only the enquirer to be blind. I suppose I thought if the OP was blind, there'd be no need to ask us for suggestions. But perhaps the OP just isn't interested in LaTeX ;). (Or is too expert to be familiar with current introductory sources.)